# Android Date Picker month as number

Tags: android, operating-system, datepicker

In Android DatePicker, in some OS it shows Month as "Jan, Feb, Mar...Dec", on other it shows as 1,2,3..12

Is there a way to make it consistent througthout so that it should display 1,2,3.. 12 always as month?

Reason for displaying 1,2,3..12 instead of string is the localization support for various kind of languages.

Also is it advisable to do so?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: This link can be helpful [DateSlider as an alternative DatePicker for Android](http://blog.codeus.net/dateslider-1-0-an-alternative-datepicker-for-android/)

Comment: I think this is the UI pattern for each OS, is there any specific reason for the change? If not then don't play with Default UI patterns.

Comment: Ali's link is dead.  Instead use:  http://web.archive.org/web/20120529063131/http://blog.codeus.net/dateslider-1-0-an-alternative-datepicker-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" > 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Date" /> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current Date (April-10-2012): "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> 
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> 
    <DatePicker
     android:id="@+id/dpResult"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

     </LinearLayout>
```

Date picker class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import com.datepicker.R.string;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.text.format.DateFormat;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class DatepickerActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tvDisplayDate;
    private DatePicker dpResult;
    private Button btnChangeDate; 
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private String str;
    public static long UTC (int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second) {
        return 1;
    }

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    //private static final  int August =4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar. MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //  str=c.getDisplayName(c.MONTH, 2, Locale.US);

               // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

        // set current date into datepicker
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
    } 
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate); 
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 


            public void onClick(View v) { 
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    } 
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(str + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

            // set selected date into datepicker also
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
        }
    };
```

}